# El archivo PHP no encuentra una clase, pero la clase está definida

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo php llamado "purchase.controller.php" en el cual, dentro de una función llamada 'ctrCash' de la clase 'Purchases', paso variables a una función llamada 'ctrNewCashPurchase' de la clase 'CartController' que he definido. pero cuando ejecuto el proyecto, recibo el mensaje:

> "Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Class 'CartModel' not found in ... "

Si hago un var_dump dentro de la función ctrNewCashPurchase, me doy cuenta de que estoy ingresando esa función, pero me dice que no reconoce 'CartModel' y no entiendo por qué.

**Comparto el código del archivo "purchase.controller.php":**

```
class CartController{

    static public function ctrNewCashPurchase($datos){

        $tabla = "compras";

        $respuesta = CartModel::mdlNewCashPurchase($tabla, $datos);

        if($respuesta == "ok"){

            $tabla = "comentarios";
            ModeloUsuarios::mdlIngresoComentarios($tabla, $datos);

        }

        return $respuesta;

    }      

}

class Purchases {

    public function ctrCash (&$arrayCompleto, &$usuario, &$direccion1, &$direccion2, &$dia, &$hora, &$email, &$telefono, &$sesion){

        if(isset($usuario)){

             //Here I create an array
             for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayCompleto); $i++){

               $datos = array("idUsuario"=> $sesion,
                              "idProducto"=> $arrayCompleto[$i]["idProducto"],
                              "metodo"=> "Efectivo",
                              "email"=> $email,
                              "direccion"=> $direccion1,
                              "detalleDireccion"=> $direccion2,
                              "diaEnvio"=> $dia,
                              "horaEnvio"=> $hora,
                              "telefono"=> $telefono,
                              "pais"=> "ARG");

                }

             $respuesta = CartController::ctrNewCashPurchase($datos);

          }

     }

}
```

**Comparto el código del archivo "purchase.model.php", donde defino la clase CartModel:**

```
class CartModel{

    static public function mdlNewCashPurchase($tabla, $datos){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (id_usuario, id_producto, metodo, email, direccion, pais, detalleDireccion, diaEnvio, horaEnvio, telefono) VALUES (:id_usuario, :id_producto, :metodo, :email, :direccion, :pais, :detalleDireccion, :diaEnvio, :horaEnvio, :telefono)");

        $stmt->bindParam(":id_usuario", $datos["idUsuario"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id_producto", $datos["idProducto"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":metodo", $datos["metodo"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $datos["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":direccion", $datos["direccion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":pais", $datos["pais"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":detalleDireccion", $datos["detalleDireccion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":diaEnvio", $datos["diaEnvio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":horaEnvio", $datos["horaEnvio"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":telefono", $datos["telefono"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if($stmt->execute()){ 

            return "ok"; 

        }else{ 

            return "error"; 

        }

        $stmt->close();

        $tmt =null;
    }

}
```

**Y agrego este otro archivo llamado 'aux.php' en caso de que influya en algo en el error que me causa. Aquí muestro cómo envío los parámetros de 'purchase.controller.php' dentro de la función 'ctrCash'**

```
    if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){

    require ('purchases.controller.php');

    $arrayCompleto = json_decode($_POST['arrayCompleto'], true);

$usuario = $_POST['usuario']; 
$direccion1 = $_POST['direccion1']; 
$direccion2 = $_POST['direccion2']; 
$dia = $_POST['dia']; 
$hora = $_POST['hora']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$telefono = $_POST['telefono']; 
$sesion = $_POST['sesion'];


 $payments = new Purchases(); 
$payments -> ctrCash($arrayCompleto, $usuario, $direccion1, $direccion2, $dia, $hora, $email, $telefono, $sesion);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El archivo "shopping.controller.php" tiene esta línea:

```
require ('purchases.controller.php');
```

Que como sabrás incluye y evalúa el archivo especificado.

Pero en la clase "purchase.controller.php" no has incluido el archivo "purchase.model.php".

```
require ('purchases.model.php');
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Me preguntaba en qué lugar me estás diciendo que incluya al archivo de "purchase.model.php" dentro de "purchase.controller.php". Directamente al principio del código de ese archivo, o en algun lugar en especial ?

Comment: Sí, me refiero a que en el archivo  "purchase.controller.php" incluyas "require ('purchases.model.php');"

Comment: Bien, entiendo. Lo hice hace un rato pero sigue sin funcionar. Me dice esto:

Warning: require(purchase.model.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\controladores\purchase.controller.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'purchase.model.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\frontend\controladores\purchase.controller.php on line 3

Comment: Es extraño, pero tienes los archivos en el mismo directorio?

Comment: Lo pude resolver! Primero no estaba poniendo lo que me dijiste. Y segundo, me faltaba colocar la ruta completa. Muchas gracias!